# Chances and status of a UK tourist Visa for a 23 year old from Pakistan on a gap year who will be going to Canada for University in September?

Tags: uk, tourist-visas

I am a 23 year old unemployed Pakistani and I want to go to the UK for tourism, accompany my parents for their conference and meet my friends. I graduated from a UK University last October and I'm currently on a gap year where I applied for my Masters. I got admitted into a Canadian University that begins its course in September. I am interested in applying for a UK tourist visa right now because my parents are going for a conference at this time and I would like to also enjoy my vacation with them. I would like to know what my chances are for getting a visa. I would also like to know what my status could be in my application? It gives options for:

- Unemployed
- Student
- Other

Thank you all in advance for any help.

Comment: 62.9%, with an estimated error of 4.1%

Comment: Just in case the OP misunderstand Doc's comment: it's a tongue-in-cheek remark. We have no idea what your chances are.